# Timecard issues

Tags: acumatica, accounting

I am trying to setup time cards for projects and am running into a problem. I want the employee to enter their time, submit their time card, the supervisor to approve the time card and then accounting to release the time card. Sounds like a simple system

I have spent the last week talking to Support and they tell me that the flow has to be the employee enters their time, their supervisor approves their individual time entries, then the employee goes back in and submits their time card, then the supervisor approves the time card and then accounting can release the time card.

This can not be right. I am wondering if any of you have had to explain this process to a customer. And lived thru it? Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to create new form or modify existing Employee screen?

Answer (score 0):

There is time entry approval and there is time card approval. Time entry approval is done by the task approver or the project manager of the project - this means you can have different people approving time entries on different projects. You can bypass this by not specifying task approver or project manager on your projects.

If you want Time Card approval only, you just need tp create an Assignment and Approval map for Employee Time Card screen.

You then go to Time and Expenses preferences and use the approval map for Time Card approvals.

The process then goes as follows:
1. Employee creates the time card and submits it.
2. Time Card changes status to pending approval, optionally a notification can be sent to the approver.
3. Once approved, the time card can be released by Finance. You can make Finance a delegate of all your employees so they can view the time card record as well as make changes if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Glen,
I find that if you have a someone assigned as a task approver you cannot submit the time card.  The task approver has to approve the time on that task before the employee can submit.  I find that if I take the task approver and the the Project Manager out of the picture, then I can submit the timecard.  Then the supervisor of that employee can see that the timecard needs approved on the communications approval task.  That way we can build the dashboard to show approvals to the department supervisor.    I am still having problems getting the Accounting department the ability to Release the timecards.